# What is wrong with my subset codes to filter my data frame based on specific values of 2 columns?

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

I have a data frame in R called `dd1` and it contains around 20 columns. I am trying to create a new data frame called `dd2` which will contain records from `dd1`, filtered on these criteria:

```
 (1) where column UseFor = "ML"
 (2) where column Attrition = "Yes"
```

My code stands as follows:

```
dd2<-(subset(dd1,UseFor %in% c("ML"), Attrition %in% c("Yes")))
```

My issue is that I am getting a data frame (`dd2`) which is empty.

What is wrong with my `subset` codes? Is there an easier way to achieve what I want, may be with the `dplyr` package?

Comment: you should add your dataset as well.i vote to close this question

Comment: I don't see how my data set would help to better understand the problem at hand.

Comment: This should help `subset(dd1,UseFor %in% c("ML") & Attrition %in% c("Yes"))`. As in `?subset` _subset logical expression indicating elements or rows to keep_

Comment: @A.Suliman Thanks, Exactly what I needed. Please post as an answer and I'll vote accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `?subset` documentation

> subset: logical expression indicating elements or rows to keep: missing values are taken as false.

So in your case, you need to put conditions together as follows

```
subset(dd1,UseFor %in% c("ML") & Attrition %in% c("Yes"))
   User UseFor Attrition
1    A     ML       Yes
4    B     ML       Yes
```

However, I think you confused between `subset` and `dplyr::filter`, which works as follows

```
library(dplyr)
filter(dd1,UseFor %in% c("ML"),Attrition %in% c("Yes"))
   User UseFor Attrition
1    A     ML       Yes
2    B     ML       Yes
```

## data

```
dd1 <- read.table(text = "
   User  UseFor Attrition  
A  ML Yes   
B  ML No  
A  AL Yes   
B  ML Yes  

",header=T)
```